# i am trying to refactor my angular code according to john papa's style guide- I am getting an unknown injector error - unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

Unknown provider: freeCodeCamperServiceProvider <- freeCodeCamperService

```
    angular
    .module('plunker')
     .factory('freeCodeCamperService', freeCodeCamperService);

     freeCodeCamperService.$inject = ['$http'];

      function freeCodeCamperService($http){

      var service ={
    getPostsRequest: getPostsRequest,
    getPostsResponse: getPostsResponse
  };

  return service;
  // 2F4F4F
  function getPostsRequest(){
    return $http.get('http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot').then(getPostsResponse);
  }

  function getPostsResponse(response){
    modifyDate(response);
    return response;
  }

       function modifyDate(response){
    for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
      response.data[i].timePosted=new Date(response.data[i].timePosted).toDateString();
        }
       }
     }
```

Here is the link to my plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/Fw5ko4kafIg9r1KzZwA3

Answer (score 1):

That's becuase you are creating module again in controller

```
 angular
      .module('plunker', [])
      .controller('mainController', mainController);
```

add only

```
angular.module('plunker')
```

in your controller

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/lkXXAdILg8KbOsOBnTT8?p=preview)